# How to fix db query error: failed to connect to server - please inspect Grafana server log for details

Tags: mysql, datasource, grafana

i'm new in Grafana. Im wanted to configure the mysql in grafana as the datasource. But my database is not a local database which is cloud database in mysql. How can i configure that? because i'm trying to configure it say `"db query error: failed to connect to server - please inspect Grafana server log for details"`

Anyone know how to change that? or how to configure mysql database in grafana (not local database). Please Help. Thank you

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTm2q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Docker host using IP address of your machine follow below steps:

1. Open the CMD
2. IPCONFIG /ALL
3. Look for the IPV4 address under **WiFi** or
   **vEtherner**, in my case its 192.168.1.24 and 172.45.202.1 respectively
4. Then try accessing the app hosted in docker container with mapped port (e.g. 1433/5436)
5. It works on 192.168.1.24:1433 and 172.45.202.1:1433 in the same way to access all container apps hosted using docker